# Openlayers : TypeError: t.getType is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, openlayers

I want to drag and drop marker on map and show position.
When I use this code to drag and drop of feature:

```
var modify = new Modify({ source: this.vectorSource });
his.map.addInteraction(modify);
```

occurred this error:

> TypeError: t.getType is not a function

Answer (score 1):

If you need to move a feature on map, you need to use an Interaction but not Modify. There is not move interaction in openlayers you need to create one. This is my DragInteraction

```
import PointerInteraction from 'ol/interaction/Pointer';
import { MapBrowserEvent, Feature } from 'ol';
import Event from 'ol/events/Event';

type DragEventType = 'moveend';
export class DragInteractionEvent extends Event {
    feature: Feature;
    mapBrowserEvent: MapBrowserEvent;
    constructor(type: DragEventType, feature: Feature, mapBrowserEvent: MapBrowserEvent) {
        super(type);
        this.feature = feature;
        this.mapBrowserEvent = mapBrowserEvent;
    }
}
// tslint:disable: only-arrow-functions
// tslint:disable: space-before-function-paren
export class DragInteraction extends PointerInteraction {
    constructor(theFeature: Feature) {
        super({
            handleDownEvent(evt: MapBrowserEvent): boolean {
                const map = evt.map;
                const feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function (f) {
                    return f;
                });
                if (feature && theFeature === feature) {
                    this.coordinate_ = evt.coordinate;
                    this.feature_ = feature;
                    return true;
                }
                return false
            },
            handleDragEvent(evt: MapBrowserEvent) {
                const deltaX = evt.coordinate[0] - this.coordinate_[0];
                const deltaY = evt.coordinate[1] - this.coordinate_[1];
                const geometry = this.feature_.getGeometry();
                geometry.translate(deltaX, deltaY);
                this.coordinate_[0] = evt.coordinate[0];
                this.coordinate_[1] = evt.coordinate[1];
            },
            handleMoveEvent(evt: MapBrowserEvent) {
                if (!this.cursor_) {
                    return;
                }
                const map = evt.map;

                const feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function (f) {
                    return f;
                });
                const element = evt.map.getTargetElement();
                if (feature) {
                    if (element.style.cursor !== this.cursor_) {
                        this.previousCursor_ = element.style.cursor;
                        element.style.cursor = this.cursor_;
                    }
                } else if (this.previousCursor_ !== undefined) {
                    element.style.cursor = this.previousCursor_;
                    this.previousCursor_ = undefined;
                }
            },
            handleUpEvent(evt: MapBrowserEvent): boolean {
                this.dispatchEvent(new DragInteractionEvent('moveend', theFeature, evt))
                this.coordinate_ = null;
                this.feature_ = null;
                return false;
            },
        })
    }
}
```

You can use like this

```
this.dragInteraction = new DragInteraction(feature);
this.dragInteraction.on('moveend', (evt: DragInteractionEvent) => {
    console.log('evt', evt);
})
```

Comment: You can check this [link](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/custom-interactions.html) that i use for reference